# PHP MongoDB. Check if embedded document contains integer

Tags: php, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and trying to do an integer search in embeded documents. The collection I have is following

```
db.inventory.insertMany([{
    "store": "abc store",
    "games": [{
            "gameId": 12254,
            "score": 88
        },
        {
            "gameId": 12258,
            "score": 70
        },
        {
            "gameId": 12262,
            "score": 98
        }
    ]
}, {
    "store": "xyz store",
    "games": [{
            "gameId": 18244,
            "score": 88
        },
        {
            "gameId": 18248,
            "score": 25
        },
        {
            "gameId": 18252,
            "score": 66
        }
    ]
}]);
```

What I want to search in the collection is for example `122` in `games.gameId` and get the following result

```
[{
    "store": "abc store",
    "games": [{
            "gameId": 12254,
            "score": 88
        },
        {
            "gameId": 12258,
            "score": 70
        },
        {
            "gameId": 12262,
            "score": 98
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: You can try convert the numeric field value to a _string_ ([$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/)) and then do a _regex_ search - in a (aggregation) query.

Comment: Thanks @prasad_. Isn't there any possibility I could do integer search? since I am not very much experienced in MongoDB, I will need some solid reasons to convenience my manager for the data type conversion.

Comment: You dont have to change (update) the data - convert the data within the aggregation query's pipeline as part of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$filter` to iterate loo of `games.gameId` array of number
- `$toString` to convert number to string
- `$regexMatch` to match above converted string have any "122" string
- `$ne`, the filtered result should not be empty []
- `$expr` is expression condition to use aggregation operators

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $ne: [
      {
        $filter: {
          input: "$games.gameId",
          cond: {
            $regexMatch: {
              input: { $toString: "$$this" },
              regex: "122"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      []
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pnwA_bqZ04r)

- php syntax if i am not wrong,

```php
$query = [
  '$expr' => [
    '$ne' => [
      [
        '$filter' => [
          "input" => '$games.gameId',
          "cond" => [
            '$regexMatch' => [
              "input" => ['$toString' => '$$this'],
              "regex" => "122"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ],
      []
    ]
  ]
];

$cursor = $collection->find($query);
```